# Duplicate events from Logitech G613 Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, hardware, bluetooth, keyboard-event

For some **tiime** (sic!) now, I've been getting random duplicate events from my Logitech G613 Bluetooth keyboard. I've no idea how it's happening, and **iit** (again!) seems to happen with all keyboard keys - <kbd>i</kbd> twice, <kbd>I</kbd> once and <kbd>G</kbd> once while writing this post, although I know I've also seen it happen with <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and others. There's no indication of low battery.

From `xev`, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>?</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x6bf, subw 0x0, time 36745630, (2213,1242), root:(2379,1546),
    state 0x11, keycode 34 (keysym 0x3f, question), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3f) "?"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3f) "?"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x6bf, subw 0x0, time 36745651, (2213,1242), root:(2379,1546),
    state 0x11, keycode 34 (keysym 0x3f, question), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3f) "?"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x6bf, subw 0x0, time 36745679, (2213,1242), root:(2379,1546),
    state 0x11, keycode 34 (keysym 0x3f, question), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3f) "?"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3f) "?"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x6bf, subw 0x0, time 36745700, (2213,1242), root:(2379,1546),
    state 0x11, keycode 34 (keysym 0x3f, question), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3f) "?"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

There's nothing extra in the systemd journal when these duplicate events happen.

**II'm** running Arch Linux and **GGNOME**.

I tried connecting the dongle to another PC with the same general setup, and got the same result. I also got similar results on Windows 10, so this seems to be a broken keyboard.

Comment: Can you check this keyboard behavior after connecting it to other devices?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the tip! I got the same result on another PC.

Comment: Well, that strongly indicates that your keyboard is faulty.